# Clear Dependent field error in parsley js

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I have a custom parsley validator that I am writing that checks a group of fields for uniqueness. Everything works great except that when I fix a unique error the field that I did not change remains errored. This is of course because the manageFailingFieldTrigger adds an onchange only for the field that got changed. I think if I could figure out how to tell manageFailingFieldTrigger to validate a group instead of a field onchange that would fix my issue, but I can't figure out how to do that.

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('unique', function (value, requirement) {
        console.debug("Validating: " + value + "\nrequirement: " + requirement);
        console.debug($(requirement + '[value="' + value + '"]'));
        var matches = 0;
        $(requirement).each(function(i, val) {
          if ($(this).val() == value) {
            matches++;
          }
        });
        if(matches > 1) return false;
        return true;
    })
        .addMessage('en', 'unique', 'This value must be unique');
```

HTML (lot's of extraneous stuff removed):

```
<form id="upload_form" method="POST" action="/school/student/upload_finish" data-parsley-validate>
            <input type="text" name="data-0-1" class="column-1" value="student2@ehrtutor.com" data-parsley-group="column-1" data-parsley-unique=".column-1"/>
            <input type="text" name="data-1-1" class="column-1" value="student3@ehrtutor.com" data-parsley-group="column-1" data-parsley-unique=".column-1"/>
            <input type="text" name="data-2-1" class="column-1" value="student7@ehrtutor.com" data-parsley-group="column-1" data-parsley-unique=".column-1"/>
            <input type="text" name="data-3-1" class="column-1" value="student1@ehrtutor.com" data-parsley-group="column-1" data-parsley-unique=".column-1"/>
            <input type="text" name="data-4-1" class="column-1" value="student4@ehrtutor.com" data-parsley-group="column-1" data-parsley-unique=".column-1"/>
            <input type="text" name="data-5-1" class="column-1" value="student2@ehrtutor.com" data-parsley-group="column-1" data-parsley-unique=".column-1"/>
            <input type="text" name="data-6-1" class="column-1" value="student3@ehrtutor.com" data-parsley-group="column-1" data-parsley-unique=".column-1"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to accomplish what I wanted:

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('unique', function (value, requirement) {
    var matches = 0;
    $(requirement).each(function(i, val) {
      if ($(this).val() == value) {
        matches++;
      }
    });
    if(matches > 1) return false;
    return true;
})
    .addMessage('en', 'unique', 'This value must be unique');

window.Parsley.on('field:success', function() {
    // In here, `this` is the parlsey instance of #some-input
    //Ugly hack
    if("unique" in this.constraintsByName)
    {
        for(var field in this.parent.fields)
        {
            var fieldInstance = this.parent.fields[field];
            if(fieldInstance.$element.hasClass(this.constraintsByName["unique"].requirements.substring(1)) && fieldInstance.$element.hasClass('parsley-error'))
            {
                fieldInstance.validate();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsley doesn't (yet) deal very well with interdependent fields. The easiest way to deal with it IMO is to enclose your `inputs` in a `div` and add the validation to that `div` (see [this example](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/custom-validator-events.html)). The validation could add/remove a "duplicate" class for duplicates.

Otherwise you can trigger an `'input'` event, or call `validate()` on the other fields you want to update.

Comment: Would you mind looking at my proposed answer and seeing if you see any issues with it?